# Add HSTS header to my domain but NOT add the header if the request is an API::P request

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I used the Negated Regular Expressions in location but it does add the header but removes everything else that existed before. Even if I add it doesn’t consider the rest only hsts. I am not sure what is the best way to do this. add a header for anything else but "don't add this HSTS header if we're on API::P".

```
location ~ (?!^/p/) {
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
}
```

or

```
location ~ ^(/p/) {
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
}
```

Here is the logic that I have in mind.

```
if location == "/p/":
    pass
else:
    add_header ...HSTS...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of performance considerations, avoid using regex whenever possible. Either use two locations duplicating everything else that cannot be moved one level up:

```
location / {
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    ... common configuration
}
location /p/ {
    ... common configuration
}
```

or use the `map` block (however this actually will make at least one PRCE library call):

```
map $uri $hsts {
    ~^/p/    "";
    default  "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
}
server {
    ...
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security $hsts always;
    ...
}
```

If evaluated variable used in the `add_header` directive will be empty, nginx won't add a header with an empty value - instead it won't add such a header at all.

For the two-locations configuration, every request started with `/p/` will be handled with the `location /p/ { ... }`, and every other request will be handled with the `location / { ... }`. There is absolutely no need to use any regex locations for this particular case.

Please note that `add_header` directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.